# php - Is switch always better than a lot of elseifs?

Tags: php, switch-statement, if-statement

I am not so familiar with switch in php, but I heard if your code has a lot of elseif, it's better to use switch instead. I tried to change the code below into switch, but since I am checking two or three values at each elseif, it seems using elseif instead of switch is more logical to me (maybe I'm wrong).

So my question is, what do you suggest for the code below? Elseif or switch?

And if I want to change the code into switch, could you give me some hint?

Thank you so much in advance!

(By the way, block_check and report_check are checkboxes, and reported_msg is text)

```
public function block_user(){
    if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        $block_check = $_POST['block_check'];
        $report_check = $_POST['report_check'];     
        $reported_msg = $_POST['reported_msg']);

        if((!($block_check)) && (!($report_check))){
            echo "dont send, both not checked";

        }elseif(($report_check) && ($reported_msg == '')){
            echo "dont send, msg box is empty";

        }elseif((!($report_check)) && ($reported_msg != '')){
            echo "dont send, report_check is not checked";

        }elseif(($block_check) && (!($report_check)) && ($reported_msg == '')){
            echo "just process block";

        }elseif((!($block_check)) && ($report_check) && ($reported_msg != '')){
            echo "just process report";

        }elseif(($block_check) && ($report_check) && ($reported_msg != '')){
            echo "process both block and report";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're checking multiple values like that, you might be stuck with elseifs. There's nothing wrong with them, it's just more to type and slightly more difficult to read.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment. I will just use elseif.

Comment: You use a lot of unneeded parentheses. It takes longer for the interpreter to run your code if it is larger like that. For example, your first if statement ( `if((!($block_check)) && (!($report_check))){` ) can be rewritten like so: `if(!$block_check && !$report_check){`.

Comment: @C0deH4cker Thanks for your comment! Learned something I didn't know. I'll definitely fix it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch is really good in some situations but really bad for others. In your specific situation I would use if/elseif conditions.

I use `switch` when the condition is simple and the expression is simple. If the condition has more than one variable and the expression is longer than about three lines I wouldn't use a switch.

Here's a good example of a good switch:

```
switch ( $type ) {
    case 'banana': 
        $valid = true;
        $price = 1;
        break;
     case 'apple': 
        $valid = false;
        $price = 2.52;
        break;
}
```

Comment: As you suggested, I will just use elseif. Thank you for your clear answer!

Answer (score 2):

It's about readability and taste for the most part, quite honestly. I prefer elseif statements because it allows for more flexibility if conditions become more complex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to stick with elseif in this case.

Answer (score 1):

To optimize your code, you want to put the most frequently used `if` statements at the top of the block of `elseif` statements.  Otherwise, the only difference is in readability of your code, which is actually a great reason to use `switch` statments.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will definitely apply the optimization you suggested.

Comment: Do do it for "optimization". Do it for readability. `switch` has the *tremendous downside* of not allow arbitrary expression evaluation at each branch junction.

Comment: @pst can you provide an example, just to clarify for me?